# Defining TypeScript typing for module gives TS2665?

Tags: syntax, typescript, tsc, typescript1.8, tsd

Trying to migrate from old `tsd.json` to `typings.json`. Previous my `.d.ts` had:

```typescript
declare var modname: modname.modname;

declare module modname {
    export interface modname {
        new (): modname;
    }

    export interface foo {
        bar: string;
    }
}

declare module "mod-name" {
    export = modname;
}
```

Then due to errors I changed the first lines to:

```typescript
declare var modname: modname.modname;

declare namespace modname {
```

But then got:

> TS2665: Module augmentation cannot introduce new names in the top level scope.

Maybe I am meant to install the Typings differently? - I notice strange scaffolding being automatically added to my definition files, which are installed with:

```
typings install github:user/typ/mod-name/mod-name.d.ts --save
```

Answer (score -4):

> TS2665: Module augmentation cannot introduce new names in the top level scope.

This no longer an error in the Latest `Master` version of typescript `npm install typescript@next`

Consider using this version for various reasons : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/getting-started.html#nightly-typescript

Comment: Thanks, trying with `@next` now. Results: reverted syntax and got `TS2666: Exports and export assignments are not permitted in module augmentations.` from the `export = modname;` line.